# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was working on some React Native code (shown below):

```
checkPars = () => {
        var params = useParams();
        if (params) {
            if (params.photoId) {
                this.setState({
                    photoId: params.photoId
                });
                this.fetchComments(params.photoId);
            }
        }
    };
```

And I got this error:

**Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

I looked on the page, but I was confused. It said that I should put the hook on the top level of a functional component, or at the top level of a custom Hook. But my code was in a **class**, not a function! What should I do?

Comment: You can't use Hooks inside class Components. Write a Function Component HOC to wrap your class, there you can use the Hook, always following the Rules of Hooks, that is, call them in the body of the Component itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `React Hooks` in `Class` Components only `Functional` Components
It's what the Error is telling you. So ask yourself does this really have to be a Class Component? or can you just use a Functional One? The Code you showed us doesn't help to determine what option is best for you. Chances are It's the later.

Answer (score 0):

According to React hooks naming convention, this function called `useParams()` is treated as hook even if it's a normal function.

in case you are using React Navigation, you can access screen parameters as props as below

```js
class Myscreen extends React.Component {
  checkPars = () => {
    const { route, navigation } = props;
    const params = route.params;
    if (params) {
      if (params.photoId) {
        this.setState({
          photoId: params.photoId,
        });
        this.fetchComments(params.photoId);
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    // Render UI...
  }
}
```